# Route that doesn't use a controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Hi I would like to use a route that doesn't use a controller. To be clear what I want to achieve I will first show you my code of the view called index.blade.php:

```
<div class="form-group" id="work-bar"  >
    {{Form::open(array('route'=>'user.store.work', 'method'=>'post'))}}
    <div class="center-bar">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="column-make">
                {{Form::text('order_name', '',array('class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'work-name'))}}
                <div id="BarDropDown" href="#" >
                    <select class="form-control" id="BarSelectDropDown" name="worktypes" >
                        <option  selected value="order" >Offerte</option>
                        <option value="project">Project</option>
                        <option value="task">Taak</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                {{Form::hidden('route', Request::path() )}}
                {{Form::submit('Maken',  array('class' => 'btn btn-default', 'id' => 'work-submit'))}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{Form::close()}}
</div>
```

Okay that's just a form with a dropdownlist. Here is the code of my route called routes.php:

```
<?php
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'user', 'before'=>'auth'),function(){
    Route::resource('usergroups', 'UsergroupsController');
    Route::resource('orders', 'OrdersController');
    Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
    Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksController');
    Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectsController');

    Route::post('works',array('as'=>'user.store.work'), function() {
        $action = 'store';
        if (Input::get('worktypes')=="project") {
            return App::make('ProjectsController')->$action();  
        }
        elseif(Input::get('worktypes')=="order") {
            return App::make('OrdersController')->$action();
        }
        else{
            return App::make('TasksController')->$action();
        }
    });
});

Route::group(array('prefix'=>'user'),function(){
    Route::post('login',array('as'=>'user.login.post', 'uses'=>'UserAuthController@postLogin'));
    Route::get('logout',array('as'=>'user.logout', 'uses'=>'UserAuthController@getLogout'));
});

Route::get('/',array('as'=>'home', 'uses'=>'IndexController@getIndex'));
Route::post('/',array('as'=>'home', 'uses'=>'IndexController@getIndex'));
```

So dependent of what I have selected from my dropdownlist I would go to ProjectsController or OrdersController or TasksController. To store a project or a order or a task. But the following route doesn't work:

```
Route::post('works',array('as'=>'user.store.work'), function() {
    $action = 'store';
    if (Input::get('worktypes')=="project") {
        return App::make('ProjectsController')->$action();  
    }
    elseif(Input::get('worktypes')=="order") {
        return App::make('OrdersController')->$action();
    }
    else{
        return App::make('TasksController')->$action();
    }
});
```

And that's because I get the following error:

```
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given
```

The reason why I get that error is, because I have to give 1 more argument for that expected parameter. So I should change this:

```
Route::post('works',array('as'=>'user.store.work'), function() {
```

With this:

```
Route::post('works',array('as'=>'user.store.work',  'uses'=>'OrdersController@store'), function() {
```

But I don't wanna use the store() method from the OrdersController, because then I can only store orders to the database. Gladly I'm waiting for your answer. Anyway thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your route to:

```
Route::post('works',array('as'=>'user.store.work', function() {
    // your function code here
    }
));
```

callback should be inside array and not as 3rd parameter